# How to refactor jquery mask to handleInputChange reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to create a mask to my input field, but I don't know how to do that using pure ReactJs, I have this funcion in jQuery how does the job I want, but I don't know how to refactor to React way, any help?

```
$("#cpfcnpj").keydown(function(){
    try {
        $("#cpfcnpj").unmask();
    } catch (e) {}

    var length = $("#cpfcnpj").val().length;

    if(length < 11){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("999.999.999-99");
    } else if(tamanho >= 11){
        $("#cpfcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    }

    // adjusting focus
    var elem = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        elem.selectionStart = elem.selectionEnd = 10000;
    }, 0);
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).val(currentValue);
});
```

Reactjs function:

```
handleInputCpfCnpjChange = e => {
    //ADD Mask validation here
};
```

my input:

```
<input
   id="cpfcnpj"
   type="text"
   placeholder="CPF/CNPJ"
   className="form-control"
   name="cpfcnpj"
   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
   value={this.state.cpfcnpj}>
</input>
```

Comment: Put your jquery code in the componentDidMount() lifecycle and use handleInputChange to update the state

Comment: I tried to do that, but when I write something on Input, the application Returns me a error: TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default(...)(...).mask is not a function

Comment: Include jQuery and other needed libraries/plugins in your index.html file

Comment: Reading by google, I realized that a lot of people say that it is not a good practice to use jQuery with React, because it leaves DOM manipulation too heavy, is there any way to do that jQuery validation using pure React?

Comment: Sure, you migt want to read up how the unmask jQuery library works and try implement that in react

Comment: There are plenty of libraries compatible with react for input masking that don’t depend on jQuery, you don’t have to build it from scratch.